# why doesn't std::move work?

Tags: c++11, reference, promise, move, future

I am trying to compile the below code in VS2013 for learning future and promises in C++. But it throws error , 
`cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::promise<std::string>' to 'std::promise<std::string> &&`'.

Why does this error occur?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<thread>
#include<future>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int func(promise<string> && prms)
{

    int k;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000;i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < 1000000; j++)
    {
        k += i + j;
    }
    prms.set_value("Thread set");
}

int main()
{
    promise<string>prms;
    future<string> ftr = prms.get_future();
    thread t(func, std::move(prms));
    cout << "Waiting in main\n";
    string str = ftr.get();
    cout << str << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: After changing `func` return type to `void`, and initializing `k`, the code compiles cleanly with Visual C++ 2015.

Comment: [MSVC bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/729886/std-thread-constructor-doesnt-handle-movable-object). As Alf says, it's fixed in VS2015.

Comment: ok, but do we need to do the above steps to make it compilable in VS2015?